# jQuery - Identifying an object by its position (index) among siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is identify an element by its position within a div. I've tried the code below and it works, but I'm curious if there's a much more efficient way to do this.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <button>One</button>
  <button>Two</button>
  <button>Three</button>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.container button').on('click', function(e) {
  clickedBtn = e.target;
  btnNum = 0;

  $('.container button').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this)[0] === clickedBtn)
      btnNum = i+1;
  });

  $('.result').text('Clicked button #' + btnNum);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are looking for index based in siblings you can call the [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index1) without any arguments.

```js
$('.container button').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.result').text('Clicked button #' + $(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>One</button>
  <button>Two</button>
  <button>Three</button>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Ahh, so many jQuery functions to keep track of! That is excellent, it's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack just to mention about your original code: `$(this)[0]` is the same to `this`, `e.target` can simply be `this`, it is a good idea (in future cases) to add `return false;` after `btnNum = i + 1;` to prevent next unnecessary iterations of `.each()`. Keep in mind that `.index()` counts all siblings ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qvgkbdo3/)) - it can cause incorrect behaviour in future.  And don't forget to mark answer as correct one.